# Xcode project directory

Tags: xcode, directory

Are there any variables or preset functions that can retrive the project/app directory or location. I need to be able to call this variable or function from an implementation file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSURL *)appURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
}
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html